# Compatible form of initial vector

Tags: r

```
f <- function(x,y){
   x^2+y^2
}

vars <- c("x","y")
fD <- rep(0,length(vars))
for(i in 1:length(vars)){
  fD[i] <- Deriv(f,vars[i])
}
```

Error in `fD[i] <- Deriv(f, vars[i])`:

> incompatible types (from closure to double) in sub-assignment type fix

What is the compatible form of initial `fD`?

Comment: Please make the title clear. See [ask]. Also, `Deriv` is not a base R function, do you mean `deriv`?

Comment: Your answer is probably that fD should be a list, since `deriv` returns an expression.